# v-model doesn't support input type="file"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I can not use `v-model` with file input, Vue says I must use `v-on:change`. Ok so I can use `v-on:change`, but how can I bind the "content" of the input file to a `data` property?

Let's say I want to bind it in a component to `this.file`:

```
export default {
  data() {
    file: null
  },
  // ...
}
```

Here is the HTML part:

```
<input id="image" v-on:change="???" type="file">
<!--                           ^- don't know how to bind without v-model -->
```

How should I do the binding?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In the `onchange` event you should pass the event object to a function and handle:

```
onFileChange(e) {
  var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
  if (!files.length)
    return;
  this.createImage(files[0]);
},
```

For more information refer https://codepen.io/Atinux/pen/qOvawK/

Comment: `this.createImage(files[0]);` is a different method which is not included in the sinppet above, but the codepen link has it. I think it would be better if you could add that here as well, codepen link might expire, but the answer would remain.

Comment: Is it a good practice to use the "data:image/png;base64" plain text value for create the image on server-side?

Answer (score 20):

Using `v-model` with a file input makes no sense, because you can't set a value on a file input - so what should a two-way binding do here?

Just use  `v-on:change`

Comment: Directly on the input tag, I agree, but in a component meant to handle file uploads in a generic way it is extremely normal to want to include a custom v-model pattern. (I get that the question is, literally, about type="file" but I think a better answer would be: make a custom input)

Comment: the @change doesn't behave correctly when I upload the same file twice (it doesn't think anything has "changed")  so setting a value to null would make sense in order to reset the input.