# The GET method is not supported for route form2/submit. Supported methods: POST. Laravel 9 Vue js 3

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js

I wanted to create a function to submit image and text to database through a form but I keep getting the error :
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/form2/submit 500 (Internal Server Error)

this is my route :

```
Route::post('/form2/submit', [Form2Controller::class, 'store']);
```

The controller :

```
public function index()
    {
        return Form2::all();
    }
    
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $image = $request->file('image');
            $path = $image->store('public/images');
            $data['image'] = $path;
        }
        $response = Form2::create($data);
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'data' => $response
        ], 200);
    }
```

The form :

```
<Form @submit="saveData()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                   <Field name="nomor"
                                    type="text"
                                    class="form-control3"
                                    v-model="form2.nomor"
                                    placeholder="         Nomor Telfon"
                                    :rules="isRequired"
                                />

                            
                                <br>
                                <ErrorMessage name="nomor"/>
                                <br>
                                <Field name="image"
                                    
                                    type="file"
                                    class="form-control3"
                                    v-model="form2.image"
                                />
 </Form>
```

The Script :

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import { Form, Field, ErrorMessage} from 'vee-validate';

export default {
  components: {
    Form,
    Field,
    ErrorMessage
  },
  data() {
    return {
      form2: {
        nama: '',
        alamat: '',
        nomor: '',
        email: '',
        image: '',
      },
    };
  },
  
  methods: {
      isRequired(value){
          if (value && value.trim()){
              return true;
          }
          return 'This is required';
      },
      validateEmail(value) {
        // if the field is empty
        if (!value) {
          return 'This field is required';
        }
        // if the field is not a valid email
        const regex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
        if (!regex.test(value)) {
          return 'This field must be a valid email';
        }
        // All is good
        return true;
      },
      saveData(){
          axios.post('/form2/submit', this.form2).then(
              response => {
                  console.log(response);
                  this.$toast.success(`Data berhasil dikirim`,{
                    position: "bottom",
                  });
              }
          ). catch(error => {
              console.log('error');
              this.$toast.error(`Terjadi kegagalan`,{
                    position: "bottom",
                  });
          })
      }
  }
};
</script>
```

I tried adding method="POST" to the form but it still won't help, why am I getting this error when I'm not using any GET method?

Answer (score 0):

Read [this article](https://stackabuse.com/axios-multipart-form-data-sending-file-through-a-form-with-javascript/) about sending multipart/form-data using axios:

```
axios.post('/form2/submit', this.form2, {
    headers: {
       "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
})
```

Try preventing default behavior

```
saveData(e){
   e.preventDefault()
}
```

Also you can't directly bind input file types:

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803012/v-model-doesnt-support-input-type-file) helps you to handle

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    image: ''
  },
  methods: {
    onFileChange(e) {
      var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
      if (!files.length)
        return;
      this.createImage(files[0]);
    },
    createImage(file) {
      var image = new Image();
      var reader = new FileReader();
      var vm = this;

      reader.onload = (e) => {
        vm.image = e.target.result;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    },
    removeImage: function (e) {
      this.image = '';
    }
  }
})
```