# How can I change time max value when uploaded video file at Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js

I would like to change input time maximum value after uploded video file at vue javascript. Even though I set attribute maximum after uploded file with javascript, I couldn't change max value of time input.. Can you give me an idea? Thank you in advance..

```js
<CCardBody>
             <CRow>
                 <CCol>
                    <CRow id="input_file" form class="form-group">
                      <CCol sm="3">Video File(MP4, FLV)</CCol>
                      <CCol sm="3">
                        <input
                            type="file" ref="video" id="duration-video"
                            :v-model="videogallery.video" accept="video/*"
                            @change="onVideoChange($event, 'video')"
                            @input="setFileInfo()" horizontal
                        />
                      </CCol>
                      <pre id="infos"></pre>
                    </CRow>
                  </CCol>
                </CRow>
                <CRow>
                  <input type="time" id="end" name="end" placeholder="Enter time" min="5:00" max="10:00">
                </CRow>
</CCardBody>
<script>
 ....
methods: {
    setFileInfo() {
         var myVideos = [];
         let self = this;
         window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
         var files = document.querySelector("#duration-video").files;
         myVideos.push(files[0]);
         var video = document.createElement("video");
         video.preload = "metadata";

                video.onloadedmetadata = function () {
                      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(video.src);
                      var duration = video.duration;
                      self.duration = duration;
                      let hours = duration / 3600 | 0;
                      let minutes = duration % 3600 / 60 | 0;
                      let seconds = duration % 60;
                      this.durationsEnd = hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
                      var end = document.getElementById('end');
                      end.setAttribute("max", this.durationsEnd);
                    };
                    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
                },
                onVideoChange(event, ref) {
                  this.$helpers.onVideoChange(
                    event,
                    ref,
                    this,
                    this.videogallery,
                    this.file,
                    this.img
                  );
},
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of mistakes and bad practices in your current attempt.  Vue very rarely requires the use of the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) interface. Vue manages the DOM for you, so it's *usually* a mistake to query or manipulate the DOM directly.

Instead of code like `document.createElement`, add the element to your template and use [v-if](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html) to conditionally render the element after you have the video file.

Instead of code like `document.querySelector` or `document.getElementById`, use [template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#template-refs)

Instead of code like `end.setAttribute` use [v-bind](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind) in your template with a data variable.

Also, using v-model on `<input type="file">` is a [mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803012/v-model-doesnt-support-input-type-file).  The fact that you're using v-bind with v-model (`:v-model=`) is actually masking this error.  v-model should never be used with v-bind.  Remove the v-model from the input and just use the event passed to the `@input` function

Finally, your duration code could use some improvement. You need to take into account when hours/minutes/seconds are < 10 (single digit).  Right now you get  durationsEnd values like `"1:4:9"` when you need to pad these digits with zeros, e.g. `"01:04:09"`

I tested this code as working correctly:

```html
<template>
  <!-- file input -->
  <input
    id="duration-video"
    ref="video"
    type="file"
    accept="video/*"
    horizontal
    @input="setFileInfo"
  />
  <!-- time input -->
  <input
    id="end"
    type="time"
    name="end"
    placeholder="Enter time"
    min="5:00"
    :max="maxTime"
  />
  <!-- conditionally rendered video element -->
  <video
    v-if="videogallery.video"
    ref="videoEl"
    :src="videogallery.video"
    controls
    @loadedmetadata="setDuration"
  />
  <div>max time: {{ maxTime }}</div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      videogallery: {
        video: ''
      },
      maxTime: '10:00'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setDuration(e) {
      const duration = e.srcElement.duration
      this.maxTime = this.secToHHMM(duration)
    },
    setFileInfo(event) {
      const media = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
      this.videogallery.video = media
    },
    // function comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/49366878/6225326
    secToHHMM(number) {
      let hours = Math.floor(number / 3600)
      let minutes = Math.floor((number - hours * 3600) / 60)
      let seconds = Math.floor(number - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60)
      let H, M, S
      if (hours < 10) H = '0' + hours
      if (minutes < 10) M = '0' + minutes
      if (seconds < 10) S = '0' + seconds
      return (H || hours) + ':' + (M || minutes) + ':' + (S || seconds)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```